# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') even though useState() is initialized with array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, typeerror

I've got "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')", **even though useState() is initialized with array**. The error occurs only in one component. Other components, which, I think, are also using useState and useEffect the same way, don't resolve with this error.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react/cjs/react.development";
import * as constants from "../../../../constants";

export default function Keywords(props) {
  const [movieKeywords, setMovieKeywords] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchKeywords = async () => {
      const data = await fetch(
        `${constants.TMDB_BASE_PATH}movie/${props.id}/keywords?api_key=${constants.API_KEY}`
      );

      const jsonData = await data.json();
      setMovieKeywords(jsonData.keywords);
      console.log("xdd");
    };

    fetchKeywords();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-wrap">
      {movieKeywords.map((keyword) => {
        return (
          <div className="border font-oxygen m-1 rounded-xl cursor-pointer text-xs text-gray-300 px-2 py-1">
            <p>{keyword.name}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I will be glad if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please don't send an image and post the actual code.

Comment: Check out your `jsonData` in `useEffect`. Maybe its `undefined`.

Comment: `jsonData.keywords` may be `undefined` and therefore the line `setMovieKeywords(jsonData.keywords)` could set your `movieKeywords` state variable to `undefined`

Comment: jsonData.keywords is not undefined. The thing is that, when I add console.log and update the component without updating the whole DOM, everything works fine.

console.log(data), console.log(jsonData), console.log(jsonData.keywords) all returns with responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably just off by just a few ms in the timing of the API call and the rendering.  A good practice is to check for the existence of the array you're mapping before trying to render any JSX. Set your initial state to null and do [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) on your map line.

Refactor your component something like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react/cjs/react.development";
import * as constants from "../../../../constants";

export default function Keywords(props) {
  const [movieKeywords, setMovieKeywords] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchKeywords = async () => {
      const data = await fetch(
        `${constants.TMDB_BASE_PATH}movie/${props.id}/keywords?api_key=${constants.API_KEY}`
      );

      const jsonData = await data.json();
      setMovieKeywords(jsonData.keywords);
      console.log("xdd");
    };

    fetchKeywords();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-wrap">
      {movieKeywords?.map((keyword) => {
        return (
          <div className="border font-oxygen m-1 rounded-xl cursor-pointer text-xs text-gray-300 px-2 py-1">
            <p>{keyword.name}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Notice the `movieKeywords?.map`, this will not execute map until `movieKeywords` is not null, meaning it will wait until the fetch resolves and your state is set.

Comment: Thanks, You are right, I was off by few ms, because the "id" prop I used in API call was a state in parent component and was initialized to string. Also thanks for letting me know about optional chaining, didn't knew that one ;).

Comment: `id` as a string shouldn't matter, so long as it is present.  If you are getting `id` asynchronously in the parent component, meaning `Keywords` is rendered before `props.id` exists, that could also cause problems, but I can't know for sure without seeing the parent component as well.

Comment: what this feature called? I want to learn more about...

obj?.method()

Comment: That is the optional chaining that I linked in my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

"jsonData.keywords is not undefined." - The error is actually informing you that it is though. `setMovieKeywords(jsonData.keywords);` updates the state and then `movieKeywords` is undefined and unable to access a `.map` property/method.

From what I see, you are missing the `props.id` as a dependency for the `useEffect` and `fetch`. It sounds like `props.id` is initially not a valid value for the API request and you are getting an undefined `keywords` response.

You should only make the API request if you have all the required parameters, and your code should be robust enough to handle potentially invalid and bad responses.

1. Add `props.id` to the `useEffect` hook's dependency array.
2. Only make the `fetch` request if `id` is truthy.
3. Handle potentially rejected Promises from `fetch`.
4. Handle any potential bad state updates with undefined values.

Example:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react/cjs/react.development";
import * as constants from "../../../../constants";

export default function Keywords({ id }) {
  const [movieKeywords, setMovieKeywords] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchKeywords = async (id) => {
      try { // <-- (3) use try/catch to handle rejected Promise or other exceptions
        const data = await fetch(
          `${constants.TMDB_BASE_PATH}movie/${id}/keywords?api_key=${constants.API_KEY}`
        );

        const jsonData = await data.json();

        if (jsonData) { // <-- (4) only update state if defined response value
          setMovieKeywords(jsonData.keywords);
        }
      } catch(error) {
        // handle any errors, log, set error state, ignore(?), etc...
      }

      console.log("xdd");
    };

    if (id) { // <-- (2) only fetch if `id` is truthy
      fetchKeywords(id);
    }
  }, [id]); // <-- (1) add `id` as dependency

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-wrap">
      {movieKeywords?.map((keyword) => { // <-- Use Optional Chaining in case `movieKeywords` becomes falsey for any reason
        return (
          <div className="border font-oxygen m-1 rounded-xl cursor-pointer text-xs text-gray-300 px-2 py-1">
            <p>{keyword.name}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank You!